# Excel VBA Form Checkbox

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

Hey I am new to Excel VBA and need someone's help. Following is what I am looking for:

If a certain unlinked (form) checkbox(topleftcell?) is checked Then
   certain checkboxes below it(.offset?) will be checked off (if they are not already)

I can't use cell names since the same code above will apply to bunch of columns.

This is what I have sort of

```
Set aaa = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller) 
With aaa.TopLeftCell 
    If aaa.Value = 1 Then 
        rsp = MsgBox("Check boxes below?", 4)
        If rsp = vbYes Then
             certain checkboxes(.offset?) below will be unchecked &
             .offset(0,0).value= "na"
```

Comment: using `.topleftcell` is unreliable because if the rows/columns shrink/grow then your code will fail. How many checkboxes do you have say in 1 column?

Comment: Actually, if the column grows or shrinks, it will not affect the position of the checkbox to which the module above is linked. That checkbox will always be at the top. And right now, I have 15 column but only want certain ones checked if the top most checkbox is checked

Comment: What if the rows grow/shrink?

Comment: That shouldn't matter. My topmost cell will always be there and whenever I check that, I want certain checkboxes below (whose position wouldn't change) to be checked too.

Comment: ok so say, how many checkboxes are there in one column?

Comment: I meant to say I have 15 checkboxes above and severals tens of columns where each column follows the same structure.

Comment: Kool. Posting a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that your checkboxes are placed as shown in the image below. I deliberately didn't align them.

[image]

Ok here is a small trick that we will use. Right click on all checkboxes in `column 1` one by one and click on `Format Control`. Next go to the `Alt Text` tab and type `1`. For Column 2 checkboxes, type `2` in the `Alt text`. Repeat this for all 15 columns.

[image]

Now assign the below macro to all the top checkboxes.

```
Sub CheckBox_Click()
    Dim shp As Shape, MainShp As Shape
    Dim Alttext As String

    '~~> Get the checkbox which called the macro
    Set MainShp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    '~~> Get it's alternate text
    Alttext = MainShp.AlternativeText

    '~~> Loop through all checkboxes except the checkbox which called it
    '~~> and check for their alt text
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shp.Name <> MainShp.Name And shp.AlternativeText = Alttext Then
            '~~> If the top checkbox is checked then set the rest as checked
            If MainShp.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
                shp.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1
            Else
                shp.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Now when you click the top most checkbox then it will check all the checkboxes below which have the same `Alt text` as the top checkbox.

Comment: I really appreciate your time. I am little concerned because as I had mentioned, I don't wall all the checkboxes below to check off. Only "certain" ones. Though your method work, I was hoping to stay with my code and perhaps use something along the lines of using intersect, topleftcell.offset somehow. Can .offset be simply used here without linking to my cell or how about using the left, top, height and weight of the cell containing the chekbox.

Comment: `I don't wall all the cells below to check off.` Cells? or Checkbox?

Comment: If not, I can go ahead and use your code but it needs to work so only certain defined checkbox are not checked. For example, if the top checkbox is checked or then the 3 and 5 checkbox will need to be checked too. Thanks again

Comment: keep the `alt text` of 3 and 5 checkbox the same as top checkbox. like i mentioned earlier using `.topleftcell` with `.offset` will be highly unreliable. The code that i gave you will not fail no matter where you keep the checkboxes..

Comment: Of course. So the code works like I want. Only thing is I don't have 15 column but several tens of column so looks like I'll be coping and pasting bunch of checkboxes. But more importantly this works. Thanks Sid!!