# Make only one checkbox tickable in a row?

Tags: excel, checkbox, vba

I have 5 to 6 check boxes (active x) in a row and I have 50 rows.

Is there a way to make only one checkbox tick-able in a row ( only one answer either 1,2,3,4 or 5)?.

Any simple vba to do this , I don't want to write a code to every checkbox.

Comment: Have you considered using a Group Box with 5-6 Option Buttons in each row instead? The Group box makes sure, that only one option button is selected...

Comment: You should use an `Option Button` inside of group boxes. my anser [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490084/optionbutton-index-issue/17491835#17491835) explains how you can get this, this is also much more intuitive to the user as, atleast with me, when i see check box i assume multiple selections are allowed, when i see option I know I can only choose one. Also with this route there is no additional code needed once you set up the groups the default actions of the `Option Buttons` do the rest of the work on there own.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done BUT Why use ActiveX Controls and so much extra coding? Why not data validation list? See this screenshot

[image]

If you still want a VBA Solution then I would recommend using FORM Controls and use their `ALT Text` to configure it. I infact have in one of the SO posts shown how to use group similar controls using `Alt Text`

[image]

**EDIT:**

If you want to go down the VBA road then here is another alternative, which `DOESN'T` use any FORM/Active X controls

Arrange the sheet as shown in the image below.

[image]

Now paste this code in the Sheet Code Area

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then ClearCells Target.Row, 2
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(4)) Is Nothing Then ClearCells Target.Row, 4
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(6)) Is Nothing Then ClearCells Target.Row, 6
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(8)) Is Nothing Then ClearCells Target.Row, 8
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(10)) Is Nothing Then ClearCells Target.Row, 10
End Sub

Sub ClearCells(r As Long, c As Long)
    For i = 2 To 10 Step 2
        If i <> c Then
            With Cells(r, i)
                .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
                .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
                .ClearContents
            End With
        End If
    Next i
    With Cells(r, c)
        With .Borders(xlDiagonalDown)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With .Borders(xlDiagonalUp)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Now all the user has to do is select any of the grey cell and it will be `Crossed Out`. Also if there is any other cross in the same row then it will be removed.

[image]

[SAMPLE FILE](http://sdrv.ms/18y9nI2)

Comment: Can you share the post? I never knew you could group controls based only on the Alt Text.

Comment: Still trying to find it but did you not like the idea of using Data Validation?

Comment: i cant use data validation, It is a kind of feed back questions & ratings from scale 1 to 5 so it is easier to tick the appropriate. the problem is all the check boxes can be ticked .

Comment: Ok Found it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391848/excel-vba-form-checkbox

Comment: If you want to go down the VBA road, There is another alternative, which doesn't use any FORM/Active X controls. WOuld you be interested in it?

Comment: Ohh, you mean with the addition of VBA you can group the object based on Alt Text, from readin your question I assumed you mena the Excel handles objects with the same Alt Text as a group. Also the OP specificazlly says he doesn't want to add VBA to every checkbox.

Comment: @user2140261: I have updated my post demonstrating on how to achieve what you want without using any FORM/ACTIVEX control. Sample file attached at the end of the post. Try clicking on different grey areas.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your efforts , i really appreciate your help and thats why i come here and look for help. actually i cant alter my excel cells because lots of merging of cells involved. so above solution is not an answer for me. while searching for an answer i fond this little script. Based on group name we can set all the checkboxes to true or false. Now i would like to ask you experts to change this code to , if any checkbox in this group is selected other checkboxes in this group shoud be set to false. I hope this is  not too difficult to make it work.

Comment: this is the code and "t1" is agroup name
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim s As Shape
 For Each s In Shapes
    If s.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
        If TypeName(s.OLEFormat.Object.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
            If s.OLEFormat.Object.Object.GroupName = "t1" Then
                s.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value = False
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next s
End Sub

Comment: if everything fails, then i will use option buttons.

Comment: Why such the opposition to the Option Buttons by everyone? This is 100% exactly what they were designed for.

Comment: @user2140261: I am not sure whom are you referring to but I am not opposed to using controls in the worksheet. However I would prefer using normal code or data validation list rather than using 350 controls (50 Rows * 6 Checkboxes/OptionButtons + 50 Frames) in a worksheet... :)