# Excel VBA matrix of checkboxes - only one in column AND row(?)

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

The one-sentence summary of my problem will sound familiar:

> I have a, let's say, "matrix" of checkboxes, and I want them to behave like radio buttons.

BUT: please don't tell me to use `radio buttons` instead, unless you know how to group those in a way that when you check one of them, NO OTHER button can be selected in the same row AND column.

I have a column of items and each item has 3 checkboxes like so:

```
player  C   A1  A2
------------------
item1  [ ] [ ] [ ]
item2  [ ] [ ] [ ]
item3  [ ] [ ] [ ]
item4  [ ] [ ] [ ]
item5  [ ] [ ] [ ]
item6  [ ] [ ] [ ]
item7  [ ] [ ] [ ]
...
itemN  [ ] [ ] [ ]
```

For the sake of explanation let's suppose the items stand for players on a hockey team and you want to name your captain and assistant captains.
In an ideal world, you'll select 3 players (1 captain `C`, 2 alternate captains `A1` and `A2`). In which scenario, the following rules ALWAYS apply:

```
1. One player cannot hold more than one role
2. The same role cannot be assigned to more than one person.
```

So if I select player3 to be captain, i want to see this as the result

```
player  C   A1  A2
------------------
item1      [ ] [ ]
item2      [ ] [ ]
item3  [x]        
item4      [ ] [ ]
item5      [ ] [ ]
item6      [ ] [ ]
item7      [ ] [ ]
...
```

Is that doable without some nasty coding? Because WITH nasty coding it is, it's just i'm not sure it's worth all the effort.

(Also, I don't necessarily want to go all fancy and stuff, but i want something fancier than:

```
player  
-------------
item1    [ ]
item2    [ ]
item3    [C]
item4    [ ]
item5    [A]
item6    [A]
item7    [ ]
...
```

because first, I still want to be a little fancy, and secondly, checking the checkboxes should perform other actions too.)

Comment: `please don't tell me to use radio buttons instead` Why use controls at all? You may want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658251/make-only-one-checkbox-tickable-in-a-row)

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. Secondly, I know i said i didn't want to go all fancy, but i DID say i want it to meet a certain minimum level of fancyness. Can you imagine a business tool looking like that? Clicking cells that are designed to imitate the behavior of radio boxes, users would think the developer was going for something he was not skilled enough to achieve so he settled for a "There, i fixed it"-kind of way. Please don't get me wrong, no offense intended and i do appreciate your input, it's just what you suggested wouldn't cut it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This code-snippet placed in the code of the worksheet you want to have the checkboxes in should do the trick:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim r As Range: Set r = Sheet1.Range("B2:E10")

  If Not Intersect(r, Target) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
      If Target = "[x]" Then
        Target = [ ]
        Intersect(Sheet1.Rows(Target.Row), r) = "[ ]"
        Intersect(Sheet1.Columns(Target.Column), r) = "[ ]"
      Else
        Intersect(Sheet1.Rows(Target.Row), r).ClearContents
        Intersect(Sheet1.Columns(Target.Column), r).ClearContents
        Target = "[x]"
      End If
    End If
  End If

  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note that the codename of the sheet you want to do this on needs to be "Sheet1", and you need to define the name of the range containing the checkmarks in the set-statement at the top of the sub.